# API request works with postman, but not in Node.js (request)

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, postman

I am working on a project that talks with an API, my script is in nodeJS (it's a big project so I will give you a very simplified version)

Essentially when I do a PUT request to the API, with the postman, it works fine,
When I do it with my Code: GET works great (so I know the URL is correct), but PUT doesn't work with my script, I get no errors on my console, and the API simple sends back the OK status, so I have no clues where it went wrong

Here is a very basic version of my script (that doesn't work either)

(I know the URL is correct)

**PUT parameters:**

```
{ method: 'PUT',
  baseUrl: 'https://fusionrv.XXXX.XX/fusion/apiservice',
  url:
   'XXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
  qs:
   { auth:
      'AUTH_KEY',
     value: 1 },
  headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' } }
```

**simple code (without the imports):**

```
request(putParams, (err, res) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    data = JSON.parse(res.body)
    console.log(data)
});
```

In Postman, I have the same baseURL and url, as well as the same params "auth" and "value", the body is set to "none", and headers are `Content-type: application/json`.

**The response (both in Postman and NodeJS):**

```
{
    "Status": "Success"
}
```

So does anyone know why it works with postman but not with the request module?
I appreciate all of you!

Comment: What you using to make the request?

Comment: How are you doing the PUT request? What tool or framework are you using? Have you tried to change the `qs` to `body`?

Comment: Sorry, I am using the request module in Node.js, and postman obviously, and it's a query string that is sent to the API, it's an empty body.

Comment: Might be this [link](https://grokonez.com/node-js/nodejs-restapis-how-to-create-nodejs-express-restapis-post-get-put-delete-requests) useful

Answer (score 4):

Add user-agent as part of the header

```
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was with the API, I needed to do a POST request and use a different URL to access it, it's a very strange API.